# Is the Wigner function a signed measure?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-space, wigner-transform

I have read in Wikipedia that quasiprobability distributions in phase space quantum mechanics may fail to be $\sigma$-additive, but I don't know in which sense this is true. If I have a Wigner distribution, for instance, it can be given by integration with respect to an absolutely continuous and presumably integrable function, correct?

In such a case, it determines a signed measure and those are sigma additive. Does this have to do with the fact that the negative part of the Wigner function may not be a finite measure? Is the Wigner function integrable in the Lebesgue sense, with both its positive and negative part integrable functions?

Comment: Are you sure you don't wish to post this to the [math overflow site](https://mathoverflow.net)? This is an excessively formal recondite question. In physics, most everything is Lebesgue integrable, continuous, integrable, and singular functions are rare. Wigner functions are *less* spikey than sharp classical functions: this is in the nature of QM. They fail Kolmogorov's third axiom because two points in phase space that are too close fail to represent mutually exclusive alternatives, by the uncertainty principle, and their probabilities don't quite add.

Comment: You might profit from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.10552).

Comment: [Blass & Gurevich go back to 2015](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.00666), informally.  However, all such mathematical discussions try to shoehorn phase space quantization into *starless* probability theory, which favors the Wigner function. Other *equivalent* ordering choices do not attract probabilistic, but work just as well, if only the readers attend to the 500lb gorilla in the room:  the ***star product***!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Would you be able to explain this comment about Kolmogorov’s third axiom? As the OP pointed out, the Wigner function defines a signed measure so it satisfies countable additivity. In what sense does it fail?

Comment: Two points in phase space too close to each other do not represent two mutually exclusive alternatives! The uncertainty principle!